# Not all variables pass from Firestore to Algolia during onCreate() function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, algolia

I am simply trying to get Firestore Functions to pass information from a newly made document from Firestore into Algolia index.  Unfortunately I am only getting some, but NOT ALL, of the variables passed over and I don't know why.  (Please review the images below for further context).

**After Document has been made in Firestore**
[image]

**What has been passed over to Algolia Index**
[image]

Please notice, not all the fields have been passed over.  However, even inside the code (see below), I am trying to explicitly call those fields and have them pass.  PLEASE HELP!

**CODE**

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Setting up and initializing.                                                  //
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const algoliasearch = require('algoliasearch');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Initialize Algolia, requires installing Algolia dependencies:                 //
// https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/javascript/getting-started/#install    //
// App ID and API Key are stored in functions config variables                   //
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

const ALGOLIA_ID = functions.config().algolia.appid;
const ALGOLIA_ADMIN_KEY = functions.config().algolia.apikey;
const ALGOLIA_SEARCH_KEY = functions.config().algolia.search_key;
const ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME = 'searchable_courses';
const client = algoliasearch(ALGOLIA_ID, ALGOLIA_ADMIN_KEY);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//ADDING A FUNCTION THAT UPDATES THE INDEX EACH TIME A COURSE IS MADE             //
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

exports.onCourseCreated = functions.firestore.document('searchable_courses/{courseID}')
.onCreate((snap, context) => {

    // Get the newly made "course" document
    const course = snap.data();

    // Trying to add all the fields from the Firestore "course" document into Algolia index.
    course.objectID = context.params.courseID;
    course.courseID = context.params.courseID;
    course.courseTitle = context.params.courseTitle;
    course.authorUID = context.params.authorUID;
    course.description = context.params.description;
    course.subscriptionRate = context.params.subscriptionRate;
    course.numberOfSubscribers = context.params.numberOfSubscribers;
    course.datePosted = context.params.datePosted;
    course.numberOfLectures = context.params.numberOfLectures;
    course.numberOfQuestions = context.params.numberOfQuestions;

  
    // Write to the algolia index
    const index = client.initIndex(ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME);
    return index.saveObject(course);
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data that arrives from the newly created document does not live in the `context` parameter.  It lives in the `snap` parameter, which is a DocumentSnapshot object.  Right now, you're overwriting all that data that you got out of the snapshot into the `course` variable.

You should just remove all the lines where you use `context.parameter.X` and pass the `course` object directly to Algolia as you got it from the document snapshot.

I suggest also reviewing the [documentation for Firestore triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) to better understand how they work.